# Android studio action bar not showing in new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

style.xml

```html
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

In my new activities my action bar wont show, im not sure why this is happening. It only appears on the first activity. And it does not appear in any other activities. Im new to android development so this may be anoob question. But its really bothering me. I have included my code for my project. thank you for reading!

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.karanvir.search.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
            android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"
            android:onClick="jump"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```css
package com.karanvir.search;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import static com.karanvir.search.MainActivity.urlGlobal;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //finding webview
        WebView webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);

//whole bunch of settings you might want to do if you .
        //do this because javascript is so wildely used that if you dont use this anywebsites you display wont be displayed properly
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //this is because on a number of phones if you dont do this it will jump to the devices default browser, and ddisplay the websview their instead.
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q="+urlGlobal);
        //reminder ask permission
        //you can load content using loaddata
        //then add type of data
        //then add character encoded were using

    }

}
```

```html
package com.karanvir.search;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intentGoogle;
    Random rn;
    SharedPreferences urls;
    AutoCompleteTextView searchBar;
    public static String urlGlobal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        searchBar=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

         rn= new Random();

        urls=this.getSharedPreferences("com.karanvir.search", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);






    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings4) {
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);



            return true;
        } else if(id ==R.id.action_settings2){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if (id==R.id.action_settings3){
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);


            return true;

        }else if(id==R.id.action_settings1){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                    .setTitle("About")
                    .setMessage("stuff");
                    return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void jump(View view){
        //intnet changing target of our code
urlGlobal=searchBar.getText().toString();
        Log.i("stuff",urlGlobal);


        //public static String urlGlobal=




       /* urls.edit().putString("url",searchBar.getText().toString()).apply();
        String Stringurls=urls.getString("url","");*/

        int pageJump = rn.nextInt(3)+1;
        if (pageJump==1){
            //google
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);
        } else if (pageJump==2){
            //YAHOO
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Yahoo.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        } else if(pageJump==3){
            //GOOGLE
            Intent intentGoogle= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoogle);

        }


    }
}
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.karanvir.search">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Yahoo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_yahoo"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.karanvir.search.Main2Activity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: share your style.xml code

Comment: I think it has something to do with the manifest ,

Comment: I would advise you using Toolbar instead. Change theme to...NoAcyionBar and include <Toolbar.../> tag in XML.

Comment: thanks for the advice im still stuck can you guys please give me a up on my post i need help

Comment: thanks for the up votes boys!

Comment: omg i realized I have made a error in my post I ment the action bar settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try above in style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and update your AndroidManifest file like above

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.karanvir.search">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
       />
    <activity
        android:name=".Yahoo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_yahoo"
       ></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: this did nothing

Comment: thanks for the post omi i apprectiate you trying to help bro

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey_400</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

> And in your Manifest add this in every Activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: this did nothing

Comment: Did you change `android:theme` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with activity theme as AppTheme.NoActionBar, hope this help you.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"       
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/login_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: will try this in the am thanks for your post bro, ill be sure to try to help you out in the future. let u know if it works tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Android Studio and add a new Activity try:

```
File -> New -> Activity -> Basic Activity
```

Then it has the ActionBar configurated by default.

[image]